# NameError: global name 'username' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I am useing Django 1.5 (with python3) with my user model,user model have midrations with south, I do syncdb and migrate good but when I do createsuperuser has this error:

```
NameError: global name 'username' is not defined
```

My user model is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in


def update_last_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
    """
    A signal receiver which updates the last_login date for
    the user logging in.
    """
    user.last_login = timezone.now()
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
user_logged_in.connect(update_last_login)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password,
                     is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254,
                              unique=True, db_index=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

I don't know that error I have in code.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in `username` to `self._create_user` method

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    # ...
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                             **extra_fields)
```

Comment: Yes, now work,that code I copy from django auth and modify, I did forget this line hehehe. Thanks you so much.